# Apache redirect to index.html for AngularJs

Tags: apache-2.2, redirect

I am building and deploying my AngularJs application.

The folder structure is as follow:

```
/
/path
/path/to
/path/to/install
/path/to/install/index.html
/path/to/install/js
/path/to/install/css
...
```

I want to redirect all requests to /path/to/install/index.html except request files exist.

Originally I put my application in /dev and my .htaccess put inside /dev is:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
IndexIgnore */*
RewriteEngine on

ErrorDocument 404 /dev/index.html

# if a directory or a file exists, use it directly
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/api
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]

# otherwise forward it to index.html
#RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^/(.*) /dev/$1 [NC,L]
```

It works fine. However, when I am going to put it in /path/to/install and change '/dev' in .htaccess, server always give me 500 Internal server error even I enter:

```
www.mysite.com/path/to/install/index.html
```

When I remove .htaccess in /path/to/install/, 500 error has gone. I have tried to put the .htaccess in /path etc. and tried to a few different path setting in .htaccess yet still cannot solve it.

When I put .htaccess in /path/to/install: I found that if .htaccess contains:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
```

only, no 500 error but if .htaccess conatins:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
IndexIgnore */*
```

or

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
```

both these two gives me 500.

I am not sure it gives clue on what the problem is. How to solve it?

Comment: Your error.log file should explain a little more about the 500 error which might help point you in the right direction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is due to wrong line seperator format for .htaccess. Use text editor to change the format to other one(CRLF/ LF/ CR) will solve the problem.